# Workflow for animating FPS characters/items for Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

In Blender, I have two objects, a human character, and an axe. I want to animate these with idle/walking/running animations and other animations per item (just the axe in this case). Then export it to Unity. Since the character and the axe are separate objects, I'm having trouble animating them, for example, in the walking animation. I found one solution that is to have a Child Of constraint on the axe and have the target bone be the hand of the character. However, this can't be exported to Unity. Maybe I also should mention they have separate armatures too, just in case.

Another solution (yet not a good one) was to just export the character animations and in Unity, parent the axe armature to the hand. Though this worked for the axe, it was a bit tedious to properly align it, which would have to be done each time I export it from Blender, like when adding new animations. Also, I don't think that it would work for other things like guns, where the gun and magazine has to be animated too.

Since I'm new to this, is there a better way to go about creating multiple items that can be held by the character, animating them, and exporting them to Unity? Is there a general workflow for this?